# Webhook на изменение баланса

Tags: мойсклад-api

На какое событие мы должны подписаться по WebHook в МойСклад что бы отслеживать актуальные изменения баланса клиента?

Answer (score 1):

Пока что нет возможности подписаться на изменение баланса. Единственный вариант - подписаться на все сущности (Create - Update - Delete), которые могут изменить баланс.